# How to find the surnames of the contacts of a user in ldap?

Tags: search, filter, ldap

[image]

[image]

I want to know the search base and filter(i.e. the ldap query) to get the surnames(sn) of Hugo Williams.

Thanks,
Samuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `basedn` : `cn=Hugo Williams,ou=users,o=mojo`
- `scope` : `base`
- `filter` : `(objectClass=*)`
- `attribute to retrieve` : `sn`

With a `ldapsearch` command line on a linux client it would be (don't forget to add the host/credentials if needed) :

```
ldapsearch -s base -b "cn=Hugo Williams,ou=users,o=mojo" "(objectClass=*)" sn
```